# The integral of: $1/(1+x^2)^{5/2}$

Tags: integration

I am fairly new to calculus and only know the basics (I will be learning about integration by parts and substitution soon), but I wanted to tackle this problem with what I can do.

[This is a video by Blackpenredpen on this exact question.](https://youtu.be/7nWDBemtZTk)

His method used trigonometry, which I am sure is the optimal way to go about it, but I wondering about what is wrong with my initial method of using binomial expansion derived from the Maclaurin series.

[image]

If someone could explain why this is wrong, or whether this is just an approximation of the final integral, that would be great!

(As a side question, is it common to get an integral with infinite terms, if so, where do you put the constant of integration)?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with integrating the Maclaurin series, but then you have the problem of finding a "closed form" expression for the answer.  Sometimes there isn't one, and the series is the best you can do.  In this case though, a trig substitution is better, as you say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expressing an integral as an infinite series is quite common, although it's mostly when you can't do it in closed form, or when you have a definite integral and you can evaluate the sum afterwards. It's a neat trick to get a series that you can then use to calculate the integral numerically, or to get a finite approximation (for example in physics, where first terms in the series are usually what you are looking for).

The constant is just the indetermined zeroth power term:

$$C+x-\frac{5}{6}x^3+\cdots$$

The procedure is correct, but $x^7$ prefactor is calculated wrongly, it's supposed to be $-\frac{15}{16}x^7$; just retrace your steps and find the mistake.

Comment: Thanks, I see my mistake as I multiplied the denominator by the 6 instead of the 7.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach

$$\dfrac{d(x(1+x^2)^n)}{dx}=(1+x^2)^n+nx^2(1+x^2)^{n-1} =(1+x^2)^n+n(1+x^2-1)(1+x^2)^{n-1}$$

$$\dfrac{d(x(1+x^2)^n)}{dx}=(n+1)(1+x^2)^n-n(1+x^2)^{n-1}$$

Integrate both sides wrt $x$

$$x(1+x^2)+K=(n+1)I_n-nI_{n-1}$$ where $\displaystyle I_m=\int(1+x^2)^m\ dx$

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with the continuous series expansion.

But why I think there is a contradiction is that $x$ must be such that $\mid x\mid< 1$ for the series expansion to hold.

Comment: Your _answer_ is a good comment.